# Delayed Function in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, youtube-api

I'm working on a Wordpress site that has a collection of YouTube videos.  When a new video is added to the site, it pulls certain information into the site's database using YouTube's API (the video's duration, number of likes, views, etc).

The problem is that this information will get stale pretty quickly, so I need a way to periodically refresh the video information.

I was planning to just use wp-cron and loop through all of the videos each evening and updating them, but I'm hitting YouTube's rate limit for pulling the video information - after a while it just returns 403 Forbidden errors.

Is there a way to write code that will, say, go through the first 50 videos, wait 5 minutes, then do the next 50, until they've all been updated?

Comment: Are you looking for **sleep** routine? ;-)

Comment: Would that cause performance issues?  The script that I have already adds 500ms of sleep between calls to the API, and I wasn't sure if using sleep for 5 minutes between processing chunks of videos was a good idea.

Comment: Yuo said you want to wait 5 minutes so it sleep to use ;-). Instead - just query youtube slower - add like 100ms delay between consecutive requests etc. - similar effect. Depending on your system you may use scheduler or cron and run your script periodically - all depends...

Comment: I already have 500ms of delay between requests and I'm still hitting the limit pretty quickly.  I couldn't find an exact description of YouTube's API limits - the documentation essentially said that if you're not doing anything bad, you won't get limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to pull the list of your videos and add a field (like `DATETIME`) that indicates the last time you refreshed them. Then you limit your query to get only the top 50 rows and order your query by the `DATETIME DESC`. That ensures you always get the most stale first. Make your cron run every X mins then and let it fly.

Comment: It worked.  I am now updating YouTube video information in batches of 50 every hours.  That means that even if over 1,000 videos are in the system (not likely for some time), they'll all be updated within 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You could use sleep (300); but you will have to set_time_out (0);  so the script does not time out.